# Download an image URL in protractor

Tags: protractor

I need to download an image URL to my project folder's file. I have tried below code for that:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = './files';
a.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';  
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

But it gives error as `ReferenceError: document is not defined.`

How can we solve this or how can I download an image URL to a specified folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use npm package image-downloader: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader

Comment: Great thanks young...Its solved my problem.